# setting up gke autopilot in terraform good example

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to setup GKE using terraform on autopilot.  So far the documentation I looked at it a bit confusing.  I'm looking for a basic setup on getting things running.  I did a bit of searching on the web and I found the following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTcos7s0iDo, but this contains too much detail about setting up the vpcs and everything, is there a basic example which I can use ?

Comment: Please add more details - what exactly to you want to achieve, what's your desired setup.

Answer (score -1):

you can just edit your existing gke.tf config and add

```
maintenance_policy {
recurring_window {
  start_time = "2021-06-18T00:00:00Z"
  end_time   = "2050-01-01T04:00:00Z"
  recurrence = "FREQ=WEEKLY"
  }
}

{
enable_autopilot = true
  }
release_channel {
  channel = "REGULAR"
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).